# Why are Fortuna entropy pools reset after a reseed?

Tags: implementation, random-number-generator, fortuna

I've implemented LibTomCrypt's version of fortuna and am wondering about the pool resetting after a reseed. In fortuna.c in libtomcrypt we have the following (which is that part that adds the entropy from the pools into the key),

```
for (x = 0; x < LTC_FORTUNA_POOLS; x++) {
  if (x == 0 || ((prng->fortuna.reset_cnt >> (x-1)) & 1) == 0) { 
      /* terminate this hash */
      if ((err = sha256_done(&prng->fortuna.pool[x], tmp)) != CRYPT_OK) {
         sha256_done(&md, tmp);
         return err; 
      }
      /* add it to the string */
      if ((err = sha256_process(&md, tmp, 32)) != CRYPT_OK) {
         sha256_done(&md, tmp);
         return err;
      }
      /* reset this pool */
      if ((err = sha256_init(&prng->fortuna.pool[x])) != CRYPT_OK) {
         sha256_done(&md, tmp);
         return err;
      }
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Once the pool has been added to the key, it is reset, why is that? I realise that at that point the entropy has been included in the key, so it has been used, but why not just keep adding entropy to the pool and have it keep all the entropy from the beginning of time? Is there any disadvantage if the pools are not reset?

Comment: Well, the question here is more about whether the pools should or shouldn't be reset, based on an example implementation which does reset them. What I want to know is whether the algorithm requires the pools to be reset and what the reasons are for that.

Comment: You can download the paper from https://www.schneier.com/fortuna.pdf . Regarding the reset you are talking about: it does appear in the paper. I don't know the rationale behind it, but I suppose it has to do with avoiding poisoning of the pools. But the paper is very terse and does not give much reasons about the decisions made :-(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [noted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15432/why-are-fortuna-entropy-pools-reset-after-a-reseed#comment32363_15432) by [izaera](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/11321/izaera), that reset of the pool is explicitly specified in [Fortuna](https://www.schneier.com/fortuna.pdf), and not an implementation artifact.

The pools in Fortuna are SHA-256 hashes. By definition, in order to obtain a pool's result, the SHA-256 hash must be obtained (in the present code, that's the job of `sha256_done`). With a standard SHA-256 implementation, there is no way to continue a hash after obtaining its result (e.g. `sha256_process` could fail after `sha256_done` until another `sha256_init` has been performed). I have not checked if it is the case in LibTomCrypt, but it would be the case with the equivalent in `java.security.MessageDigest`.

This provides an incentive for a "reset of the pool": restarting the pool/SHA-256 from scratch is the simplest option compatible with obtaining the hash and making the pool able to collect entropy again, that allows to use standard SHA-256 libraries.

It would be possible to reenter the collected entropy (here, `tmp` returned by `sha256_done`). That would be more complex, and slower. Most importantly, it is not necessary for the security rationale of Fortuna, which has a large enough state beyond the pools.

---

Another argument on the same line of thought: with standard SHA-256 libraries, there is no way to save and restore the state of a hash (except by saving the whole input), when we might want to save the state of Fortuna (as compactly as possible).

Comment: Thanks! The explanation about restarting SHA256 makes perfect sense, so that helps it fall into place correctly in my mind - much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing else, it makes the output of the pool irrecoverable. One of Fortuna's goals is to make prior Fortuna outputs safe from a compromise (the discovery of all of Fortuna's current data by an adversary). If the pool continued on without a reset, with little or no entropy added before the compromise took place, the adversary could more easily calculate the past contents of the master pool.

Edit: Per M. Grieu (Merci!), let's make that "more easily verify guesses of past inputs to the master pool".

Also, I believe the OP's question is less about LibTomCrypt than about the Fortuna algorithm itself.

Comment: Discounting the counter, the master state evolves per $K←\text{SHA}_d\text{-256}(K||s)$ where $s$ is built from the pool outputs. That makes it computationally impossible to _calculate the past contents_ of master state from current contents of master state and pools, even if that fully revealed past pool outputs. However, indeed, a reset of a pool after use makes it harder to _verify a guess_ of the past contents of the master state from current contents of master state and pools.